# How is a real number a proper subset of $ℚ$! (dedekind cut)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just started studying some set theory using "Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study" and i've been stuck at the 8th and 9th page for 2 days lol. It says:

A **Dedekind left set** is a subset of $r$ of $ℚ$ with the following properties:

1. $r$ is a proper, non-empty subset of  $ℚ$
2. if $q∈r$ and $p<q$, then $p∈r$
3. $r$ has no greatest element

A **real number** is a Dedekind left set and $ℝ$ is the set of all such real numbers.

Let $q∈ℚ$. Then the real number corresponding to $q$ is $Q=\{p∈ℚ:p<q\}$

Everything is clear except "a real number is a Dedekind left set", how?? How is $\sqrt2$ a non empty subset of $ℚ$? How does it even make sense?

Any help please?! Thank you

Comment: You call $\sqrt{2}$ the set of all rationals lower than (your intuitive version of the real number) $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: If the question is "how??" the answer is "by definition".

Comment: @ancientmathematician the question is not "how?" the question is "how does it make sense?"

Comment: The answer is the same: "by definition". The book is *defining* a real number. The phrase "$x$ is a real number" is shorthand for "$x$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that 1. ... 2. ... 3. $x$ has no greatest element."

Comment: Another issue could be that the common view  $\mathbb{Q} \subset\mathbb {R} $ is incompatible with elements of $\mathbb {R} $ being subsets of $\mathbb {Q} $. If that's bothering you, then understand that in reality we don't have $\mathbb{Q} \subset\mathbb {R} $ but rather $\mathbb{R} $ has a subset (let's denote it by $\mathbb{Q}^{*} $) of _rational real_ numbers which is isomorphic to $\mathbb {Q} $. The same happens with all set inclusions in the chain $\mathbb{N} \subset\mathbb {Z} \subset\mathbb {Q} \subset \mathbb {R} \subset \mathbb {C} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Dedekind cut construction of real number from $\Bbb{Q}$. In this construction real numbers are defined as subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$, satisfing the conditions mentioned in the question.

So here the subset $$A=\{x\in\Bbb{Q}:x>0,x^2<2\}\cup \{x\in\mathbb {Q} :x\leq 0\} $$ is a Dedekind cut and **which is denoted as** $\sqrt2$.

So it is not, how $\sqrt2$ can be a subset of $\Bbb{Q}$, but this set $A$ is defined as $\sqrt2$. And if we further proceed we can see, the set $B=\{x\in\Bbb{Q}:x<2\}$ is a Dedekind cut, defined as $2$ and product is defined such that $A^2=B$, that is, $(\sqrt2)^2=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it's a little more clear, but one more doubt, how can i know what rational number is, for example, $π$ or $e$ (Euler's number) associated to? that is,  $π=\{p∈ℚ:p<??\}$

Comment: Your definition of $\sqrt2$ doesn't really work, since $-6$ is not there.

Comment: @cekami7844: Those are more complicated, but we can still approximate them, because $e$ and $\pi$ are definable as very concrete limits (e.g. by infinite sums).

Comment: @cekami7844: not every specific real number can be described as easily as $\sqrt{2}$. Even without all this Dedekind stuff, I think you will find that explaining something about $\sqrt{2}$ is much easier than explaining something about $\pi$ (eg trying proving $\pi$ being irrational). But once you learn a little more analytical properties of $\pi$ (like sequences converging to it) you may well describe it as a Dedekind cut yourself. Be patient and continue with study of real analysis.

Comment: Well, I wrote wrong $A$. Someone please edit it, because I can't due to some technical glitch.

Comment: Edited the definition of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\sqrt2$ is the set of all rational numbers $x$ which are negative or that $x^2<2$. This set is certainly not empty, it contains all the negative rationals, etc.

But wait, you might say, this is somehow circular. How do you know to define it by $x^2<2$? Well, $\sqrt\cdot$ is not an integral part of our language. Instead we have $2$, which *is* a rational number, and then we say that $\sqrt2$ is the unique positive solution to $x^2-2=0$, so we define the Dedekind cut as above, and we can then show in the field $\Bbb R$, given by these Dedekind cuts, $\sqrt2$ is in fact the cut we defined, i.e. the positive solution for $x^2-2=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really get it.. ‍♂️

Comment: Which part? It will be very helpful if you can explain *what* you don't get *in my answer*.

Comment: Also did you try drawing a line, pretending it to be the rational numbers, and then trying to understand how $\sqrt2$ would look like?

Comment: I don't get the same thing i don't get in my question, how is $\sqrt2$ "the set of all rational numbers $x$ such that $x^2<2$. i dont how it makes sense, intuitively. And i don't get why you say: the set of all rational numbers "which are negative", why negative?

Comment: Do you see why $1^2<2$ and $1.2^2<2$ and so on?

Comment: yes i do? why??

Comment: Do you see why you need to include the negative rationals in order to make this into a Dedekind left set?

Comment: Because it has to be closed to the left i.e. if $q∈r$ and $p<q$, then $p∈r$?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @cekami7844: I think your main issue here is that you have some idea already of "what is $\sqrt{2}$" and you find that idea incompatible with what is being described here. If that's the case then try to ask questions about your existing idea and you will find that many problems with it and these can be resolved by doing what is done here.

Comment: @cekami7844: whatever idea you may have about real numbers, has to be discarded temporarily and then start afresh with the idea that a real number is nothing but a left Dedekind set. Once you do that you will find that this new description is really consistent with whatever intuition you had of real numbers and in fact it can be used to prove any property of real numbers which you perhaps assumed without proof.

Answer (score 0):

**"a real number is a Dedekind left set", how??**  - from now and in the future you'll know, that numbers are sets. All operations, all properties between numbers now will be corresponding operations, properties between sets. Welcome to real life.

Comment: i know that already, 1 is defined as $1=\{Ø\}$, 2 as $2=\{Ø, \{Ø\}\}$ but at least that's more intuitive at least. Thanks for the "answering" lol

Comment: Would you like me delete it? I just wanted to support mentally. If it help you, other approaches to real numbers - by fundamental sequences, by decimal fractions - are the same: factorization with respect to some equivalence property.

Comment: No don't delete it bro don't worry, i'm just very confused with this part 

Comment: I felt the same way, but 30 years ago. As if promised and deceived. But I'm used to it or realized that there are no other options. Create your definition - at least I will be grateful.