# Dedekind cut with $-3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im studying some set theory, and my book gives me this definition:
"A **Dedekind left set** is a subset of $r$ of $ℚ$ with the following properties:

1. $r$ is a proper, non-empty subset of  $ℚ$
2. if $q∈r$ and $p<q$, then $p∈r$
3. $r$ has no greatest element

A **real number** is a Dedekind left set and $ℝ$ is the set of all such real numbers.

Let $q∈ℚ$. Then the real number corresponding to $q$ is $Q=\{p∈ℚ:p<q\}$"

Then it gives me this exercise:

"Write down a description, in terms of rational numbers and operations of $ℚ$, of the Dedekind left sets corresponding to the following real numbers: -3, (and some more)"

the result of this exercise is:

$\{p∈ℚ:p<-3\}$

Now finally my question:

Does this mean that $-3=\{p∈ℚ:p<-3\}$? Isn't this also saying that "the real number corresponding to $-3$ is $-3$? by the definition above?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729946/how-is-a-real-number-a-proper-subset-of-%e2%84%9a-dedekind-cut).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thats my question..

Comment: Yes, one should read both questions, they belong together.

Comment: @DietrichBurde If you mean other people yeah i guess, for me i read it already since i asked it lol

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @Dietrich, you should set up context with previous questions, when relevant. Especially when you were the one who recently asked them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh i didnt know that okay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote the following comment from your previous question:

> Another issue could be that the common view  $\mathbb{Q} \subset\mathbb {R} $ is incompatible with elements of $\mathbb {R} $ being subsets of $\mathbb {Q} $. If that's bothering you, then understand that in reality we don't have $\mathbb{Q} \subset\mathbb {R} $ but rather $\mathbb{R} $ has a subset (let's denote it by $\mathbb{Q}^{*} $) of *rational real* numbers which is isomorphic to $\mathbb {Q} $. The same happens with all set inclusions in the chain $\mathbb{N} \subset\mathbb {Z} \subset\mathbb {Q} \subset \mathbb {R} \subset \mathbb {C} $. – [Paramanand Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh)
> , posted on [22 June, 2020](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729946/how-is-a-real-number-a-proper-subset-of-%e2%84%9a-dedekind-cut?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment7668209_3729946).

The point here is that $-3$ the rational number is *not* $-3$ the real number, and neither is $-3$ the natural number.

Your task is to understand how do the rational numbers embed into the real numbers, as defined here by Dedekind left sets. So when we write $$-3 = \{q\in\Bbb Q\mid q<-3\},$$ the left $-3$ is a real number, it is a set of rational numbers, whereas the right $-3$ is a rational number (which is presumably a set of ordered pairs of integers, which are sets of ordered pairs of natural numbers, which are presumably the von Neumann ordinals; but even if the rational numbers are just "given", it does not change anything here).

But after we have done all that, and maybe a bit more (i.e. defining $\Bbb C$ as well), we can decide that it is easier to work under the assumption that the rational numbers *are* real numbers, and the above tells you exactly what are the "new rational numbers".

Comment: Thank you i really got it now! One more question though.. if real numbers are defined using rational numbers, aren't real numbers in the end rational numbers? lol sorry for the wordplay

Comment: No. They are sets of rational numbers. If your groceries are in a bag, does that make your bag part of your groceries?

Comment: lmao that's right i didnt think of that, thank you 

Comment: +1 there for analogy of "the groceries and bag containing groceries". Also thanks for converting that comment into a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

$-3$ may now be considered as a rational number (perhaps defined as an element of the equivalence class containing the ordered pair $(-3,1)$, not sure how that book constructs the rationals) or as a real number, in which case it is the set of all rationals less than $-3$. They are different things set theoretically, but the rationals considered as a subset of the reals of course 'obey the same behavior' (with respect to addition, multiplication, order), which means there is an isomorphism between the previously constructed rationals and the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ which are considered rational; if $r$ is a rational in our old construction,
the corresponding 'rational' in $\mathbb{R}$ would be $\{ p \in \mathbb{Q} \, | p < r\}$.

Comment: ooh so the $-3$ on the left of the equation: $−3={p∈Q∣p<−3}$ is the real number $-3$ which is constructed and corresponds to the rational number $-3$?

Comment: @cekami7844 correct - one has to be careful not to overload definitions, $-3$ stands for the real number $-3$ in this context.

Comment: ooh i got it! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to clarify what the symbol $-3$ actually means in this case, because we can't write, in a formal manner $-3:=\{p\in \mathbb Q\mid p<-3\}$ otherwise we have self reference.

It might be better to write $D(-3):=\{p\in \mathbb Q\mid p<-3\}$, where $D(-3)\in \mathbb R$, and $-3\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: what does $D$ mean?

Comment: I just used it as a notation (D for Dedekind) to differentiate with the element in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: You can think of it as a map from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$, which is obviously injective but not surjective.

Comment: ooh so as i said before, $-3$ rational is defined differently than $-3$ real? because my book (classic set theory for guided independent study) doesnt construct any rational number ‍♂️

Comment: yes, strictly, the $-3\in\mathbb R$ is not the same element as  $-3\in\mathbb Q$. However, because there is an injection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$, conserving algebraic and ordering properties, it is often informally written $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$

Comment: i understand! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exactly does mean that.

The problem is, before going to construct real number (by any method, Dedekind cut, Cauchy complition) first you have to forget what you have **assumed** to be a real number in high school. Otherwise such questions will arise frequently. We also used to wonder a lot when we studied this first.

Starting with, till now we only know rational number as equivalence classes of a relation defined on the set of integers. Then we are constructing a set $R$ which contains subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$ satisfying the three conditions. After defining the operations we prove that the $R$ is a complete ordered field.

Then we embed $\Bbb{Q}$ inside $R$ by the map $q\mapsto \{x\in\Bbb{Q}:x<q\}$.
Once we show this map is monomorphism then we see $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subset $R$ and write rationals as you have written $q=\{x\in\Bbb{Q}:x<q\}$. Then we denote $R$ as $\Bbb{R}$, sets of real numbers.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you so much your answers are always very good! keep it up bro